# Does the method for computing the cross-product change for left handed coordinates?

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, coordinate-systems, cross-product

Does the method for computing the cross-product change for left handed coordinates?

Comment: Off topic, ask at http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Kirk Woll: It's not off topic for somebody working in the field of 3D graphics.  Though if that's the case, the question is probably poorly tagged.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The formula for the cross product of the vectors `(x1, x2, x3)` and `(y1, y2, y3)` is

```
z1 = x2 * y3 - x3 * y2
z2 = x3 * y1 - x1 * y3
z3 = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1
```

It is designed in a way that the three vectors `x`, `y` and `z` in the given order have the same handedness as the coordinate system itself.  This property does not depend on the handedness of the coordinate system -- for a left-handed coordinate system the vectors fulfil the left-hand rule.  You don't need to change anything about the formula.

Useful links:

- [Righthanded and Lefthanded Systems of Coordinates and the Cross Product](http://www.f-lohmueller.de/pov_tut/a_geo/a_geo85e.htm)
- [Relevant section from the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Cross_product_and_handedness)

Answer (score 1):

In left-handed coordinates, the cross product is the same magnitude simply pointed the other way. The easiest way then that I know of to convert from a right-handed coordinate system's cross-product, and a left-handed coordinate system's cross-product, is to take the components of the right-handed cross-product and reverse the signs.

Comment: This is not correct. If you reverse both signs, the resulting cross-product does not change.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: depelbaum did not say the sign of both vectors should be changed.  (S)he said the sign of all components of the right-handed should be changed, so this is basically the same as your answer.  It's wrong anyway.

Comment: @Sven, I recind my previous comment.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: Reading my last comment again, it sounds a bit harsh.  I did not intend this.  Added an answer of my own with explanations.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question. I apologize for this, the method does not change if you are given the components in a left-handed system.

Comment: I misread the question as well. I thought he wanted to transform the cross-product of left-handed vectors to right-handed space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the magnitude of the cross-product for left-handed coordinates is negative that for right-handed coordinates.

Comment: Only from the perspective of a third reference coordinate system!