# How method cross do in HLSL?

Tags: c++, hlsl

I want to know how to determine the direction of the method cross in HLSL . I mean in OpenGL, we can use the right-hand rule to get the result and in direct3d we can use the left-hand rule .
Here is thing , which rule do we use to get the direction of the result in HLSL ?

Thanks everyone . Here is the things,these day i was working on the 3D technique , and when i do exercise with the billboarding in  , i come across a problem. In this book's chapter 12 , there is a exercise about the billboarding , and the writer give an example of vertex shader which implement the billboarding . Here is the code:

```
  OutputVS AABillBoardVS(
       float3 posL : POSITION0,
       float3 bbOffset : TEXCOORD0, // Offsets to world space position.
       float2 tex0: TEXCOORD1)
  {
      // Zero out our output.
      OutputVS outVS = (OutputVS)0;

      // Vertex world position without rotation applied to make
      // face the camera.
      float3 tempPosW = posL + bbOffset;

      float3 look = gEyePosW - tempPosW;
      look.y = 0.0f;  // axis-aligned, so keep look in xz-plane.
      look = normalize(look);
      float3 up    = float3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
      float3 right = cross(up, look);

      // Rotate to make face the camera.
      float3x3 R;
      R[0] = right;
      R[l] = up;
      R[2] = look;

      // Offset to world position.
      float3 posW = mul(posL, R) + bbOffset;

      // Transform to homogeneous clip space.
      outVS.posH = mul(float4(posW, 1.0f), gViewProj);

      // Pass on texture coordinates to be interpolated in
      // rasterization.
     outVS.tex0 = tex0;

     // Done--return the output.
     return outVS;
}
```

When I use the code above , it didnot work . So I checked it , and I change the computation of right vector as **float3 right = cross(look, up);** and the result is good . So , I didnot understand why use the look to cross the up and the result is the right vector .

Answer (score 0):

This method isn't specific to OpenGL or GLSL, but you can use the same principle.  First, I'm almost positive that HLSL follows DirectX and is left handed.  However, you can determine what rule it follows by just making a test.

In GLSL, you can "print" vectors by setting fragment color equal to the vector.  Then just consider the color components of the fragment and you know what the vector equals.  In other words, a solid red fragment means that the the vect is equal to (1,0,0) and xyz maps directly to rgb.

Bearing this in mind, if you create two vectors in your shader, cross them, and "print" the resulting vector to a fragment, you can tell by the output what rule HLSL follows.

For example:

```
Vect vec1Red(1,0,0);
Vect vec2Green(0,1,0);

Vect vec3Output = cross(vec1Red, vec2Green);

GLFragColor = vec4(vec3Output.xyz,1);
```

If the color that prints out is blue, you know that the vector equals (0,0,1) and that it follows the right hand rule.  Otherwise it would be equal to (0,0,-1) which I believe ends up being black.

Comment: Computing a cross product is independent of the handedness of the coordinate system, so this will always yield (0,0,1).

Comment: But isn't he asking how to figure out how to determine the "handedness" of HLSL?  Wouldn't using the built in system cross call use the inherent handedness?

Comment: There is no such thing as "HLSL's handedness". If the result of a cross product points in a different direction using a different handedness, it's not because the vector components are different, it's because the axes are pointing in different directions.

Answer (score 0):

The cross product has only one mathematical definition, so it all depends on context. The direction of the resulting vector will follow the right-hand rule if interpreted in a right-handed coordinate system and the left-hand rule if interpreted in a left-handed coordinate system. You just need to know the handedness of your coordinate system (typically left-handed when using Direct3D, but not necessarily).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820400/does-the-method-for-computing-the-cross-product-change-for-left-handed-coordinat).